# How to mock fetch response using jest-fetch-mock

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, unit-testing, jest-fetch-mock

I am calling api in the the react functional component. I am writing unit test cases of the component. I have mocked fetch using jest-fetch-mock.

`global.fetch = require('jest-fetch-mock');`

Component.ts

```
const Component = () => {

    useEffect(() => {
      return fetch(
          'url',
        )
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(json => {
            setApiResult(json);
            setFilterResult(json?.videos);
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
          });
    }, []);

}
```

Does anyone know how to mock the fetch response for this component in jest.

Comment: I know it's not what you're looking for, but I've recently discovered [msw](https://mswjs.io/) and I'll never mock fetch again!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This one is from `jest-fetch-mock` docs directly

- Create a file `setupJest.js` file in root directory of project with following content.

```js
require('jest-fetch-mock').enableMocks()
```

- Add the `setupJest.js` file to jest.config.js or package.json wherever your jest config is.

```json
"jest": {
  "automock": false,
  "setupFiles": [
    "./setupJest.js"
  ]
}
```

now you can use `fetch` and `fetchMock` on global scope

```js
describe('testing Component', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    fetch.resetMocks()
  })
 
  it('testing something...', () => {
    fetch.mockResponseOnce(JSON.stringify({ data: '12345' }))
    const container = render (<Component/>)
    // expect statement can be wrong.
    expect(container.getByText(/12345/).toBeDefined())
  })
});
```

Comment: This will send same response in each fetch. I am making two fetch calls in the useeffect. How to handle that ?

Comment: @AjayS you can mock multiple fetch with different responses too. 
`fetch.once(JSON.stringify({ data: 'abcde' }).once(JSON.stringify({ data: '12345' }))`

this will resolve first fetch with `abcde` and second one with `12345`

Answer (score 0):

Here is small example for same using axios

```
jest.mock("axios");
 it('mock data', async () => {
        render(<Abc />);
        axios.get.mockResolvedValueOnce(data); // data is your static object
        // rest code goes here
        
    });
```